# How to merge Regex?

Tags: regex, haskell

## Background

Let say I have several `Regex` here.

```
import Text.Regex

openTag = mkRegex "<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>"
closeTag = mkRegex "</\\1>"
any = mkRegex "(.*?)"
```

## Problem

`openTag ++ any ++ closeTag` <-- Just for illustration purpose

How can I merge them? To be specific, a `Regex -> Regex -> Regex` function. Alternatively, convert a `Regex` back to `String` would be good.

`openTag ++ "hello" ++ closeTag` <-- Just for illustration purpose

Thus, I can create my own `Regex -> String -> Regex` function ultimately.

## Workaround

Manipulate the string literals.

```
import Text.Regex

openTag = "<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>"
closeTag = "</\\1>"
any = "(.*?)"

tagWithAny = mkRegex $ openTag ++ any ++ closeTag

tagWith :: String -> Regex
tagWith s = mkRegex $ openTag ++ s ++ closeTag
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Regex -> Regex -> Regex`?

Comment: You're not really trying to use a regex for HTML/XML, are you? Because no.

Comment: @dfeuer Nope, just as an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Regex` type in the `Text.Regex` is essentially a C pointer:

```
data Regex = Regex (ForeignPtr CRegex) CompOption ExecOption
```

AFAIK there is no way to recover the string representation of the posix regex, after it has been compiled. [regcomp 3 man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp).

If you’d like to operate on regular expression algebraically, wrap then in your own type to postpone the compiling or use for example [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative).

Comment: It is really sad. Thanks for your quick response @phadej.